# Can't change legend location with bbox_to_anchor

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, legend

I'm plotting data from a Data Frame and some of it goes into the primary-y-axis and the other on the secondary-y-axis. I plot in two steps as shown below:

```
ax=data[['Energy (kWh)','Reactive Energy( kVArh)','CFE',"CFE'"]].plot(figsize=(12,8),xlim=('2020-08-01','2020-08-02'),title='Energy Plots vs. Time',grid=True)
ax2=data[['PF no Cap','Power Factor CRE CdR']].plot(secondary_y=True,ax=ax)
```

I have the plots, the axis-labels and everything I need but the legend is misplaced. I want it to be outside of the plot, but when I use bbox_to_anchor a second legend is created and it only has the labels associated with ax2 (PF no Cap, Power Factor CRE CdR).

How can I move the legend, with all of the labels, to the outside of my plot?

Here I place the whole code and some pictures illustrating the problem:

```
data["CFE'"]=(data['Reactive Energy( kVArh)']-Qcap).clip_lower(0)
data['CFE']=(data['Reactive Energy( kVArh)']-Qcap)
data['PF no Cap']=np.cos(np.arctan(data['Reactive Energy( kVArh)']/data['Energy (kWh)']))
data['Power Factor CRE CdR']=np.cos(np.arctan((data['Reactive Energy( kVArh)']-Qcap_mod).clip_lower(0)/data['Energy (kWh)']))


ax=data[['Energy (kWh)','Reactive Energy( kVArh)','CFE',"CFE'"]].plot(figsize=(12,8),xlim=('2020-08-01','2020-08-02'),title='Energy Plots vs. Time',grid=True)
ax2=data[['PF no Cap','Power Factor CRE CdR']].plot(secondary_y=True,ax=ax)

ax.set(xlabel='Date',ylabel='Energy')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.3,0.7))
```

This yields the following plot:

[See how there are two legends. I would like to move the one on the left to were the one on the right is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23kgo.png)

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `plt.XXXX` family of functions acts only on the *current* axes, which in this case is `ax2` since it's the last created. I initially thought calling `ax.legend(...)` would do the trick, but that also does not work because it only considers the artists from that axes and not the ones from ax2.

Instead of recreating the legend, the simplest solution is simply to move the existing legend to a new location using `ax.legend_.set_bbox_to_anchor(...)`

```
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=ts.index, columns=list('ABCD'))
df = df.cumsum()

ax=df[['A','B']].plot(title='Energy Plots vs. Time',grid=True)
ax2=df[['C','D']].plot(secondary_y=True,ax=ax)

ax.set(xlabel='Date',ylabel='Energy')
ax.legend_.set_bbox_to_anchor((1.3,0.7))
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]